# Query MobileConnect Lists

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, contactbuilder

I need to query a MobileConnect List to delete some Contact records. Following this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Permanently-remove-Contacts-or-Subscribers-and-associated-data-from-Contact-Builder&language=en_US&type=1) on MC they status creating a MobileConnect List can then be queried into a Data Extension using the following format:

```
select SubscriberKey 
from [MyListName]
```

But I get an error creating the query stating MyListName doesn't exist.

Any ideas how I can do this and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the filtered mobileConnect list and the query present in the same business unit?

Comment: Yes they’re in the same BU

Comment: It is worth noting that this is different from the method used for querying lists in Email Studio. In Email Studio you would query a data view named _ListSubscribers instead of specifying the list name in the From clause.

Answer (score 9):

The reason for this not working is because there is currently a bug which does not update the MobileList names in the Marketing Cloud backend DB if they are renamed at any point.

I had renamed my list at some point is the reason why I am unable to query the list, if I created a list without renaming it later the query works fine.